# std::make_shared, std::unique_ptr and move constructors

Tags: c++, stl, c++11, clang

The following code compiles with clang 3.0/libc++:

```
#include <memory>

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo()
        : mem_(new int(10))
    {
    }
    std::unique_ptr<int> mem_;
};

int main()
{
    auto foo = std::make_shared<Foo>();
    return 0;
}
```

But this one doesn't (`std::string` parameter added):

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(const std::string& s)
        : mem_(new int(10))
    {
    }
    std::unique_ptr<int> mem_;
};

int main()
{
    auto foo = std::make_shared<Foo>("aaa");
    return 0;
}
```

Clang complains about the usage of a deleted constructor. To me, this makes no sense, since `std::make_shared` isn't supposed to copy the Foo instance, the only thing that would trigger the call to the (deleted) copy constructor of `std::unique_ptr`.

But lo and behold, as soon as I define a move constructor explicitly, it compiles.

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(const std::string& s)
        : mem_(new int(10))
    {
    }
    Foo(Foo&& other)
        : mem_(std::move(other.mem_))
    {
    }
    std::unique_ptr<int> mem_;
};

int main()
{
    auto foo = std::make_shared<Foo>("aaa");
    return 0;
}
```

Now, questions:

1. Why does it compile in the first example but not the second?
2. Can `std::make_shared` copy/move the object while constructing it?
3. Why does adding a move constructor fix the problem? I don't recall that adding non-default constructor should suppress an implicit move constructor.

**EDIT:** Checked and all examples appear to compile fine with gcc 4.5.1 (via ideone.com), I suspect it's the case of a clang/libc++ bug, but questions 2 and 3 still stand, plus I'd like to know which compiler is more "correct".

Comment: I don't think there is ever an implicit move constructor provided

Comment: @parapura rajkumar (1) removal of unique_ptr makes it go away (even with non-default ctor), (2) implicit move constructor is still defined according to the latest wording: http://mmocny.wordpress.com/2010/12/09/implicit-move-wont-go/

Comment: @parapurarajkumar: indeed, I recall having read discussions where implicit move constructors were a bad thing, and should be removed from the standard. However, I don't know the end of the story.

Comment: `new int(10)` doesn't allocate ten integers, only one and initialize it to 10. Maybe you want `new int[10]`?

Comment: @Joachim, no I did mean int(10), it was just an example, in this case it's not relevant, you can replace it with anything else really.

Comment: Works fine on GCC 4.6.2... try `make_shared<Foo>(std::string("aaa"))` maybe.

Comment: Compiles fine on clang++3.0 with two weeks old libc++-svn

Comment: @Cubbi:  clang has recently implemented implicit move.  You may have to disable that with an explicit deleted copy constructor to trigger the symptom.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Why does it compile in the first example but not the second?

This is a libc++ bug.  I am working on a fix for it now...

> Can std::make_shared copy/move the object while constructing it?

No, I don't believe it can.

> Why does adding a move constructor fix the problem? I don't recall
>   that adding non-default constructor should suppress an implicit move
>   constructor.

In the version of clang you're using, implicit move constructors are not implemented yet.

**Update**

Fixed: http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=11616

Comment: Wow! one hour turn around!  So if we find other bugs in clang/libc++ we can just post them to Stackoverflow to shame you into fixing them promptly?

Comment: @deft_code : I think Howard's upstanding enough to fix bugs without being shamed into it. ;-]